# Yocto fails to create a new target directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, yocto, beagleboneblack, bitbake

I have used Yocto to build an image for the BeagleBone now.

The image generated and flashed to the board fine, however, my new folder /my_storage/keys/ didn't get created in the process and of course the files that should be copied there aren't there.

My .bb recipe file is below (This is incomplete of course, but hopefully shows what i'm trying to do).

Is there anything wrong with how i'm trying to create the new /my_storage/keys/ folder?

I have inherited this project from someone else. Previously /my_storage and also /my_storage/image/ had been there already and is still there. The /my_storage/keys/ is the new folder that i'm adding but somehow it is not being created on the file system.

Perhaps, am I supposed to tell Yocto about this in another file also? Any idea would be great.

```
DESCRIPTION = "tx application"
SECTION = ""
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "java2-runtime rxtx"
SRC_URI = "file://keys/cert.pem \
           file://keys/privatekey.key \
           file://keys/CA.crt \

           ....... More stuff ................
"

DEPENDS = "rxtx"

do_install() {
   install -d ${D}/my_storage/image/
   install -d ${D}/my_storage/keys/
   install -d ${D}/app
   install -m 777 keys/cert.pem ${D}/my_storage/keys/
   install -m 777 keys/privatekey.key ${D}/my_storage/keys/
   install -m 777 keys/CA.crt ${D}/my_storage/keys/

   .............................  More stuff ...........................
}

FILES_${PN} += "app"
FILES_${PN} += "/my_storage \
            /my_storage/image/ \
            /my_storage/keys/ \
```

Comment: I don't see any issue in your recipe but, do you have an error running bitbake ? you can replace the "install -d xxxx" with "mkdir -p xxxx" command.

Comment: Is the recipe running without any error? Check out the recipe created folder in build/work/tmp/

Comment: By any chance, is `/my_storage` the mountpoint of some external storage device? If so, then you will have to copy the files at runtime, e.g. on the first boot after image installation

Comment: @CarstenHansen. It turns out that could be the case. When I flash the SD card and mount/view it on Linux, I see the keys folder inside /my_storage as expected. However when flash this to the device internal memory and boot, it looks over-written, or re-mounted.  There are different partitions. One of them is the rootfs, which contains the whole folder structure including /my_storage. However there is another partition which contains the files which should go into /my_storage. I'm not sure what is happening exactly during the flashing of the board, is stuff being copied, or actually mounted

Comment: Does your BSP use WIC to create image?